# How do I properly align divs/forms and selects inside td's?

Tags: php, html, html-table

I need to format the following elements:
[table with elements to be properly aligned](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ArOpz.jpg)

This is the snipped PHP/HTML code that generates each row of the table:

```
echo '<tr>';
echo '<td><small>' . ($i * 100 + $j) . '</small></td>';
echo '<td></td>';
echo '<td><div class="vocab-nuovo col-xs-6"><input placeholder="Nuovo vocabolo..." type="text" class="form-control"></div></td>';
echo '<td><div style="position: relative; vertical-align: middle"     class="vocab-nuovo-sel form-group">
<span style="position: absolute">
<select class="form-control" id="sel-' . ($i * 100 + $j) . '">
<option>it</option>
<option>en</option>
<option>de</option>
<option>fr</option>
</select>
</span>
</div>
</td>';
echo '<td><button onclick="addWord(this.id)" id="'. 'but-'. ($i * 100 + $j) .'" type="button" class="button-aggiungi btn btn-block btn-default">Aggiungi</button></td>';
echo '</tr>';
```

There is no style applied besides bootstrap's.
Absolute position inside span helps to keep the select left aligned and with a small size.

style="position: relative; vertical-align: middle" inside div apparently helps from putting selects outisde the table like this (don't ask me why):
[Without the attributes mentioned above](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jXBMS.jpg)

Comment: view your HTML source; it's just as good a tool as any, and developer tools in your browser. I just spent the better part of a 1/2 hour this morning myself, trying to figure out something similar to this.

Comment: It's `form-control`. I've noticed it makes select elements wonky. However, I don't have a fix for it other than not using it or adding the style as you did before.